# IOT-Pi3-Alexa-Automation - Error: 'invalid start byte' while running RPi_name_port_gpio.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, raspbian, gpio

I am new to python and Fauxmo.
I followed the same steps as mention in [github.com IOT-Pi3-Alexa-Automation](https://github.com/nassir-malik/IOT-Pi3-Alexa-Automation) link.

After executing `sudo python3 RPi_name_port_gpio.py` in terminal.

> I am getting below error.
>
> ```
> CRITICAL:root:('utf8', 'NOTIFY * HTTP/1.1
>   HOST: 239.255.255.250:1900
>   CACHE-CONTROL: max-age=300
>   LOCATION: http://XXX.1XX.1.X:55578/devices/636XXX34-3930-3XX8-3964-643XXXX03431/desc
>   NT: upnp:rootdevice
>   NTS: ssdp:alive
>   SERVER: 1.1 DLNADOC/1.50 UPnP/1.0 SITEVIEW/1.0
>   USN: uuid:6361XXX4-3XX0-3838-3XX4-64303XXX3431::upnp:rootdevice
>   CUSTOM:\xa0\x8e\x1c\xed\xae\xf1[]', 
>   319, 320, 'invalid start byte')
> ```

Kindly let me know if anything I am doing wrong or anything I am missing.

Thanks.

> **Already done**: Somebody has already raised the issue on the same github repository and even I have posted the issue in the same thread.

Comment: I would ask here: https://github.com/nassir-malik/IOT-Pi3-Alexa-Automation/issues

Comment: Hey @dan-klasson thanks for the reply. Already done :) . Somebody has already raised the issue on the same github repository and even I have posted the issue in the same thread.

Comment: Please add a comment for down voting.